# Does variable declaration have any precedence before function declaration?

Tags: javascript

I tested the following code:

```
(function(){
  var x = false;  
  function x(){
    return true;
  }  
  return typeof x;
})();
```

It returns "boolean". And only when I comment the second line:

```
(function(){
  //var x = false;  
  function x(){
    return true;
  }  
  return typeof x;
})();
```

It returns "function".
It means that if someone has declared a variable somewhere in the code before, my function declaration using the same name will fail, right? Please, someone explain it to me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, function declarations are treated as if they were written first. Then variable declarations. (That particular ordering matters very rarely, if ever.)

In variable declarations, any assignment part is treated as a separate expression statement occurring at the point in the function where the `var` statement actually appears. Thus:

```
function foo() {
  // ... some code ...
  if (whatever) {
    var x = whatever + 1;
  }
}
```

is treated like:

```
function foo() {
  var x;
  // ... some code ...
  if (whatever) {
    x = whatever + 1;
  }
}
```

Thus overall your first sample is treated as if it were:

```
(function() {
  function x() {
    return true;
  }
  var x;
  x = false;
  return typeof x;
})();
```

Note also that functions and variables share a common namespace. A `var` declaration without an assignment part for a variable name that's already been declared has no effect. (At least, I think it has no meaningful effect, but JavaScript has weird dark corners ...)

Comment: I would expect the function declarations to translate into function expression assignments written first? I.e. the code were treated as `var x; x = function x(){…}; x = false; …`

Comment: @Bergi well the JavaScript engine is free to do that I guess, but those two aren't exactly the same. The name provided in the function instantiation between `function` and the open parenthesis of the formal parameters is bound for the code in the function independent of symbols in the enclosing scope.  It's (kind-of) like `letrec` in Lisp.  (I don't know whether it's possible to construct an example that shows the difference, however.)

Comment: @Pointy: I have used a NFE for exactly that reason? Or do you mean something more specialized?

Comment: @Pointy, do you know Lisp? I have been wondering for a long time if I should learn Lisp before JavaScript to better understand functional programming. What do you think? I have already tried some Lisp and Scheme though, it seems rather different from C-like languages but interesting.

Comment: @paperstreet7 I can't say more than that I'm *familiar* with Lisp; I've never used it for a serious project. If you want to play with a modern Lisp-ish language, Clojure is really cool.

Comment: @Bergi actually via an experiment I think the "letrec"-style binding only applies to function instantiation expressions (that is, `function` as part of an expression, as opposed to a function declaration statement) that have names.  In that case, it's demonstrable that the name remains available even when the same symbol in the enclosing scope gets a new value. It seems that re-assignment to a name used in a function declaration is an error, perhaps just in newer browsers.